# how to make mysql sub query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a big Table,Now The table was subdivided into several by date

e.g.

The original table

```
UserLoginTable
+---------+------------+---------+
| UserID  | LoginTime  | others  |
+---------+------------+---------+
|  1      | 2013-03-12 | ....    |
+---------+------------+---------+
|  2      | 2013-05-12 | ....    |
+---------+------------+---------+
|  1      | 2013-06-12 | ....    |
+---------+------------+---------+
|  ...    | ...        | ....    |   
+---------+------------+---------+
```

Now the Table is:

```
UserLoginTable_Date(yyyyMM)
```

UserLoginTable_201303

```
+---------+------------+---------+
| UserID  | LoginTime  | others  |
+---------+------------+---------+
|  1      | 2013-03-12 | ....    |
+---------+------------+---------+
```

UserLoginTable_201304

```
+---------+------------+---------+
| UserID  | LoginTime  | others  |  //this table is not have UserID=1
+---------+------------+---------+
|  2      | 2013-04-01 | ....    |
+---------+------------+---------+
```

I Used

```
select count(*) from UserLoginTable_201307 where UserID=1
select count(*) from UserLoginTable_201306 where UserID=1
...
```

so I want to Kown how to show for this format by one sql

```
+--------------+ 
| UserInYear   |  
+--------------+ 
|  201303      |  //here dose find User in 201304
+--------------+
|  201306      |  
+--------------+
|  ....        |  
+--------------+
```

The best efficiency point. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `union all` as below

```
select count(*) as UserInYear from UserLoginTable_201307 where UserID=1
union all
select count(*) from UserLoginTable_201306 where UserID=1
```

**NOTE**: `union all` will not eliminate duplicates. If you don't want to duplicates you have to use `union` insetad.

Comment: i am Sorry ,I also want to kown ,how to show the result is UserInYear(not count Number),just date(201307 or 201306 ...) if count Number >0

Comment: try to add something like `having count(distinct date)>0` below the `where` clauses

Answer (score 0):

Use [`UNION ALL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html) for that:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS UserInYear FROM UserLoginTable_201307 WHERE UserID = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM UserLoginTable_201306 WHERE UserID = 1
```

If there is duplicate values for UserInYear for any year `UNION ALL` will show all while `UNION` won't show. So use `UNION ALL`.

Comment: @zt9788 - Not an issue but actually I am faster than him. (5 secs) :)

Comment: @hims056 IMO your code doesn't work, are you sure you have an alias in correct place?

Comment: @Parado - Oh a little mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

An example of Sub Query :

```
SELECT column_name, column_name1, column_number
FROM their_table
WHERE column_number = (SELECT MAX(column_number) FROM the_other_table);
```

Assume column_name as a customerNumber and
column_name1 as a checkNumber and
column_number as an amo